# What makes Toads cheer, and what do they do?

Tags: super-mario-run

During a Toad Rally, Toads will gather at the bottom of my screen and start cheering. What makes them appear? And do they have any effect on my gameplay (e.g., making stars appear, score multiplier)?

Answer (score 2):

The Toads will appear if you do certain achievements like:

- Consecutive wall jumps
- Rolling jump
- Vaulting wall jump
- Climbing jump
- Threading the ring
- Consecutive stomps

These actions will get you more Toads, and will help your coin count in the very end.

Answer (score 1):

The Toads cheer whenever you do a "stylish move". [Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/super-mario-run/2016/12/18/13983382/stylish-moves-guide-toad-rally) posted a guide on how to do all of the stylish moves. Here's a list of all of the stylish moves you can do:

- Consecutive Wall Jumps
- Vaulting Jump
- Rolling Jump
- Climbing Jump
- Consecutive Stomps
- Jump through the flaming ring

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wiki](https://mario.gameinfo.io/toad-rally), the moves that are 'stylish moves' and make toads cheer are:

- Rolling jump
- Vaulting jump
- Consecutive wall jumps
- Climbing jump
- Consecutive stomps
- Threading the ring